# Java CompletionException: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Acquire operation took longer than the configured maximum time

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Trying to make call to an aws lambda function but getting the following error:

```
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Acquire operation took longer than the configured maximum time. This indicates that a request cannot get a connection from the pool within the specified maximum time. This can be due to high request rate.
Consider taking any of the following actions to mitigate the issue: increase max connections, increase acquire timeout, or slowing the request rate.
```

Using the awsasyncclient in aws sdk v2 java which invokes the lambda function

```
LambdaAsyncClient client = LambdaAsyncClient.builder().region(region_lambda).build();
```

How to increase maximum connections or increase idle time? What can be done here?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom HTTP by calling httpClient from your LambdaAsyncClient. Then all you have to do is add your custom settings like connection timeout acquisition (you can also add other customizations to increase throughput e.g, max concurrency, max connections).

Check here: [Interface NettyNioAsyncHttpClient.Builder](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/http/nio/netty/NettyNioAsyncHttpClient.Builder.html)

Do this

```
NettyNioAsyncHttpClient.Builder customHttp = NettyNioAsyncHttpClient.builder()
.connectionAcquisitionTimeout(Duration.ofMillies(20000);

LambdaAsyncClient lambdaAsyncClient = LambdaAsyncClient.builder()
.region(region_lambda)
.httpClientBuilder(customHttp)
.build();
```

If that doesn't solve the problem, check if you're not overloading your lambda
client with multiple requests on so short a time

Also, import the netty-nio-client dependency

```
implementation "software.amazon.awssdk:netty-nio-client"
```